# DNA as software and molecular machines as hardware

Tags: bio-inspired-computing

Several scientists view DNA as some kind of software. [Chaitin](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7370/00d9e2ea2a1ae9829b681b402831d5f0e3a3.pdf) suggests that [life is an evolving software](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlYS_GiAnK8). Rothemund, Papadakis, and Winfree showed that [DNA self-assembly](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pbio.0020424) can be used as a Turing-universal biomolecular system.

DNA holds genetic information and holds the key to the evolution of living organisms. Transcription and translation mechanisms enable living cells to process information encoded in DNA. To that end, transcription and translation are fundamental mechanisms needed to enable the evolution of organisms. Molecular machines (enzymes) carry out these mechanisms by reading the information in DNA and using it to construct proteins.

If we consider molecular machines as Hardware and DNA as software;

> What algorithmic processes can independently produce the molecular machines and matching DNA code which will be executed correctly by molecular machines? How is compatibility guaranteed ( between biological software and hardware )?

Motivation: If such processes are known then we can simulate the origin of life using supercomputers.

Comment: Maybe DNA should be considered more like a database than a software. The bio-chemical rules of expression of proteins would be the software.

At the macro-level of living being, you can nevertheless consider DNA as the software of species and phenotype.

Comment: There might be some relevant papers of [Adi Livnat](http://sci3.haifa.ac.il/alivnat/). Check for example his papers with Christos Papadimitriou.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thanks for the references

Comment: @YuvalFilmus The most relevant ones: 1- Algorithms, games, and evolution
 by Chastain, Livnat, Papadimitriou, and Vazirani.  2-Sex as an Algorithm: The Theory of Evolution Under the Lens of Computation By Livnat, Papadimitriou

Comment: This a video presentation by Papadimitriou https://www.reddit.com/r/biology/comments/am84cz/computational_insights_and_the_theory_of/